# What is or how to determine the lifecycle of a ZK ViewModel

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I am trying to figure out what the typical lifecycle of a ViewModel in an ZK Applikation is and what significant points may be where a ViewModel is no longer valid.

The most important thing I would like to know is if a ViewModel which is instantiated with the load of zul page gets garbage collected if the browser gets refreshed. I can see that the init method is executed, but I don't see the finalize method being invoked.

And the second this is if there is a list or any documentation on some significant points in zk navigation where you definitely loose a former instantiated ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are cache-ing a reference to ViewModel somewhere ViewModel is bound to the page lifecycle (aka Desktop in ZK terminology).

- When you refresh page, ViewModel is recreated just as Desktop and all components are recreated with it.
- If you navigate to another URL then all components and associated ViewModel(s) are eligible to be garbage collected.

However you shouldn't rely on whether or not finalize method is being called to determine if they are purged as JVM doesn't guarantee when finalize will be called.